# SSH still asking for password even after I have tried everything (that I know of)

Tags: ssh, password, openssh

ssh is still asking for a password, even though I did everything by the book. I have included all output, right from the start. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Gary

1. Generating public/private rsa key pair and checking permissions on local host

Edit: => As it turned out, this was the problem. The key pair needed to be generated on the remote machine, not on the local machine, as «Mat» pointed it out in the very first comment.
Please read the many comments in the solution if you need to know how we got there.

```
on local computer:
mms: admin$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/admin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:ekIFdhbYVGnWsRcpyhPXRPDF5LTqYI+u6l3URsIjC90 admin@mms.fritz.box
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|      o+=o.oo*+++|
|     ..+o B +oo=o|
|       ..* E.oo..|
|       .. * =..  |
|      . S. = +   |
|     . .  o *    |
|      o .  o o   |
|       o. o      |
|      .o.o..     |
+----[SHA256]-----+

mms: admin$ pwd && ls -al
/Users/admin/.ssh
total 16
drwx------   4 admin  staff   136 Dec 26 09:37 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 32 admin  staff  1088 Dec 26 08:53 ..
-rw-------   1 admin  staff  1675 Dec 26 09:37 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff   401 Dec 26 09:37 id_rsa.pub
```

2. Copying public key:
     (from remote host, because remote host cannot be remotely accessed)

   server:.ssh ahase$ scp admin@domain-of-local-computer.com:.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   The authenticity of host 'domain-of-local-computer.com (123.456.789.012)' can't be established.
   RSA key fingerprint is 1f:14:32:84:c4:f8:4e:25:df:2d:56:49:e6:e5:79:1d.
   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
   Warning: Permanently added 'domain-of-local-computer.com,123.456.789.012' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
   Password:
   id_rsa.pub
   100%  401     0.4KB/s   00:00
3. Copying private key and checking permissions:

Edit (as per suggestion)

```
server:.ssh ahase$ scp admin@domain-of-local-computer.com:.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Password:
id_rsa
100% 1675     1.6KB/s   00:00    
server:.ssh ahase$ ls -al
server:.ssh ahase$ scp admin@domain-of-local-computer.com:.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Password:
id_rsa                                                                                                        100% 1675     1.6KB/s   00:00    
server:.ssh ahase$ ls -al
total 24
drwx------   5 ahase  staff   170 26 Dez 12:07 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 18 ahase  staff   612 10 Dez 09:19 ..
-rw-------   1 ahase  staff   401 26 Dez 09:58 authorized_keys
-rw-------   1 ahase  staff  1675 26 Dez 12:07 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 ahase  staff   410 26 Dez 09:58 known_hosts
```

4. ssh still asking for password (-vvv output) [edit after suggested changes]

   server:.ssh ahase$ ssh -vvv admin@domain-of-local-computer.com
   OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to domain-of-local-computer.com [123.456.789.012] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /Users/ahase/.ssh/identity type -1
   debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_rsa.
   debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
   debug3: key_read: missing keytype
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
   debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
   debug3: key_read: missing keytype
   debug1: identity file /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
   debug1: identity file /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.9
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9 pat OpenSSH*
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
   debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
   debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
   debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
   debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 158/320
   debug2: bits set: 1048/2048
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /Users/ahase/.ssh/known_hosts
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /Users/ahase/.ssh/known_hosts
   debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
   debug1: Host 'domain-of-local-computer.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /Users/ahase/.ssh/known_hosts:1
   debug2: bits set: 1023/2048
   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
   debug2: kex_derive_keys
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug2: key: /Users/ahase/.ssh/identity (0x0)
   debug2: key: /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_rsa (0x0)
   debug2: key: /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
   debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ahase/.ssh/identity
   debug3: no such identity: /Users/ahase/.ssh/identity
   debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_rsa
   debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
   debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
   debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_dsa
   debug3: no such identity: /Users/ahase/.ssh/id_dsa
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
   debug3: remaining preferred: password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
   debug2: userauth_kbdint
   debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1

   Password:

   debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 21 padlen 11 extra_pad 64)
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
   debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 10 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
   debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
   debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
   debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
   debug2: channel 0: send open
   debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
   debug1: Entering interactive session.
   debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
   debug2: callback start
   debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
   debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
   debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
   debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
   debug2: callback done
   debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
   debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
   debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
   debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
   debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
   debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
   Last login: Sat Dec 26 12:22:40 2015 from 123.456.789.012
   mms:~ admin$

I can't look into the log files (/var/log/auth.log or /var/log/daemon.log do not exist and I don't know where they are located). Local computer is a Mac running 10.10.5 and remote computer is a Mac running 10.6 (which can't be changed).

Thanks!

Comment: You set up your keys to allow mms to connect to server, not the other way around.

Comment: @Mat that should be an answer :)

Comment: I'm lost. How do I reverse this? Do I need to copy the local id_rsa file into known_hosts of the remote computer?

Comment: Try using `id_dsa.pub` instead of `id_rsa.pub` - the default on the server for `RSAAuthentication` will be `yes`, but it applies to `SSH` protocol version `1` only so maybe the server is set to only accept protocol version `2`, and hence not `RSA` authentication (I am just guessing ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (I'm wondering if the term "admin@mms.fritz.box" could cause any problems. Thats the name of the local host computer in the local network. fritz.box is the router's name)

No, it is [just comment](https://serverfault.com/a/743566/186199).

> ```
> debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
> ```

```
[...]
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Your client is not using the key.

To @Mat comment, on the client, you need accessible `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and on the server the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. You set it up other way round.

Comment: How can I make the client to accept the key? For my understanding: Isn't the client supposed to use the public key added to authorized_keys?

Comment: No. Client is using private `key id_rsa` as a wrote and server is authorizing the user by using the content of `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Please help me out, I copied the private key to the client leaving the name as id_rsa, but nothing changes. What do I need to do so that the client accepts this private key?

Comment: please, update the question with the actual state, permissions and verbose log. If the key is in the appropriate location (note above) and has appropriate permissions (as in your question), it should get picked up by client and used for authentication.

Comment: ok, I just changed the question and added the last -vvv output

Comment: It looks like the id_rsa is somehow corrupted. I would recommend you to start over with new key and do just the key generation on client (`sinclair`), copy the public key (as `authorized_keys`) to server (`domain-of-local-computer.com`) where you want to connect, check permissions. I am getting lost in all the moving around.

Comment: OK, it Worked! Your last comment provided the solution: `do just the key generation on client (sinclair)`. I only made the key generation on the local machine and had it mixed up! That's also what «Mat» suggested in the very first comment. I only didn't know what to do about it at first.

Comment: I'd like to edit my question so that others could benefit. For my understanding: Is it necessary to generate the key pair on my local machine at all?

Comment: It is not necessary, but it is way less trouble if you do so.